# Android toolbar with two collapsed states

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

[image][image: state 2][image: state 3]

Basically I want to achieve the same behaviour as that of the android status bar; when we swipe down from the top, a compact version with the frequently used buttons is shown. Upon swiping down further the status bar expands to show the expanded view.

I want to implement a toolbar in an app with the exact behaviour of the status bar as shown in the images. The first swipe on the `NestedScrollView` inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` should expand the the toolbar to show the compact view, and the second swipe should expand the toolbar further to show the expanded view of the toolbar
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

That is called `CollapsingToolbarLayout` the UX of that layout is to expand when swipe down and collapse when swipe up. The dependency of that layout is *Android Support Design* Library. [Here](https://www.journaldev.com/13927/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example) is a nice tutorial for this.

Comment: Please take a look again. I have updated my description to explain my requirements more clearly.